# Mysqli how to fetch all data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this query:

```
$q = "SELECT SUM(cena) AS total, MONTH( datum ) AS mesec
FROM nakupi
GROUP BY mesec";
$po = $mysqli->query($q);
$mesecna_prodaja = $po->fetch_assoc();
```

This query is selecting monthly sales data from the database. If I run this same query in phpMyAdmin I get the correct results. All sales months with total sales in each month. Problem is, that $mesecna_prodaja after fet_assoc is returning only one result, for the last month ? How can I fetch all data, as phpMyAdmin does ? I tried fetch_all, but It's not working (Internal server error).

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` is only supposed to fetch one row from the results. Getting multiple results is usually done by using a fetch method in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are looking at the results, but you need to iterate through the associative array you just fetched to view all the results.

Try something like described in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

```
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $po->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["total"], $row["mesec"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found out mysqli_fetch_assoc does get a row of data for you, in order to get all the results you're going to have to go through all the rows of your result set.

There are a many ways to do this but I'm going to show you the while loop:

```
$q = "SELECT SUM(cena) AS total, MONTH( datum ) AS mesec FROM nakupi GROUP BY mesec";

$po = $mysqli->query($q);

//$mesecna_prodaja = $po->fetch_assoc(); //This only gets the first row

//Setup an array to hold all the results
$allMyResults = array();

//Iterate through all the results until there's nothing left (which will cause the while condition to fail)
while ($row = $po->fetch_assoc()) {
     //Add $row to allMyResults
     $allMyResults[] = $row;
}

var_dump($allMyResults); //You should see all your results here.
```

The key principle here is that it's your [code's] responsibility to iterate/traverse through all the results.

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php